# Drupal ecommerce solutions

Tags: drupal, e-commerce

Hi can anyone recommend a drupal ecommerce solution.

Ideally we only want to use it to display products and not take payments. It's basically a store front rather than a store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

If Drupal 6, then Ubercart (http://www.ubercart.org/) is the clear answer. It has hundreds of helper modules and its own community developing and patching every day.

If Drupal 7, you have to decide between Ubercart and Drupal Commerce (http://www.drupalcommerce.org/), which is made (mostly) by developers who worked on Ubercart and wanted a new, cleaner framework for Drupal 7. Drupal Commerce isn't as well developed or mature and lacks a lot of the features that have been built for Ubercart.

I don't know which is right for you. Ubercart is mature and tested. Drupal Commerce is new and untested, but built with a cleaner framework and the code is much better commented. It sounds like you don't need a sophisticated store, so maybe give Drupal Commerce a shot?

Either way, they are both great modules and I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Ubercart.

http://www.ubercart.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you're not taking payments, then Ubercart is probably overkill. You could probably do what you need with a combination of the CCK and Views modules. If you needed especially complex layouts, you might consider the Panels or Context modules.

Comment: What if they change their mind? Would be a matter of just switching on payments instead of redo content.

Comment: Kevin, I agree with you, depending on the specifics of the site. I use Ubercart on several sites and i'm a big fan. There isn't a lot of detail to go on in the original question, so mainly wanted to make the point that it is possible to create a site that features products without using Ubercart. You wouldn't *NEED* Ubercart, until you needed to also sell the products on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Commerce is tightly integrated with Drupal 7 which can cause difficulties of platform customization. On the other hand Ubercart is standalone platform providing more freedom in administration.  By the way, Drupal Commerce has the peculiarity with adding product variations - each variation is created as a standalone product. 
Major drawback of both platforms is lack of documentation. But drupal commerce is rapidly developing new features and I'm sure it will provide more opportunities for new online business.

Answer (score -6):

The real solution is none. Uber Cart is horrible (just like all other Drupal modules) and will most likely not work with the recent release of Drupal 7.

If you are starting a project from scratch I would strongly advise you to use a different, more modern, easier to use CMS.